# Creation of the main function of the linked list

Tags: c++, constructor, linked-list, program-entry-point, ampersand

In the main function, we have the second line Node *head=&n1;
So my question is, the head of a node is for data, not for address, so why is address stored in head of n1 node?

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZB5F.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZB5F.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YydZY.jpg)

Comment: Please provide a [mre].  It's hard to know what your code is doing by only seeing one line of it.

Comment: That's not what it says. It says "the pointer I call 'head' is the address of the node 'n1'".

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, the head of a node is for data, not for address, so
> why is address stored in head of n1 node?

```cpp
Node *head=&n1;
```

This says I have `Node pointer` named `head` which will hold address of `n1`.

Comment: So it isn't the head of the link list? It is a pointer named head. Not the head(head and tail what we call in a link list)?

Comment: @SamikshaIyengar it will be slightly unfair to comment without actually looking at your code. if you can update your question with the code example then we will be able to help you out

Comment: Ok. I have added it now.